# How to put owl-carousel positions on left/right sides of the slider in angular 8 version?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, frontend, owl-carousel

In my project I need to use a slider. For that I found owl-carousel and integrated it in my angular project. And trying to put slider's next-arrow and prev arrows on left and right sides of the slider. But couldn't change css styles from the app.component.scss file. How can I change positions of the arrows?

Here is my app-component.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {OwlOptions} from 'ngx-owl-carousel-o';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  customOptions: OwlOptions = {
    loop: true,
    mouseDrag: true,
    touchDrag: true,
    pullDrag: true,
    dots: false,
    navSpeed: 600,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1
      },
      400: {
        items: 2
      },
      760: {
        items: 3
      },
      1000: {
        items: 4
      }
    },
    nav: true
  };

}
```

app-component.html

```
<owl-carousel-o [options]="customOptions">
  <ng-template carouselSlide>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952" alt="img 1">
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template carouselSlide>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600/771796" alt="img 2">
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template carouselSlide>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600/24f355" alt="img 3">
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template carouselSlide>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600/d32776" alt="img 4">
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template carouselSlide>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600/f66b97" alt="img 5">
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template carouselSlide>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600/56a8c2" alt="img 6">
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</owl-carousel-o>
```

in my angular.json file added these lines

```
"styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-owl-carousel-o/lib/styles/prebuilt-themes/owl.carousel.min.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-owl-carousel-o/lib/styles/prebuilt-themes/owl.theme.default.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
```

and app.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { DefaultComponent } from './components/default/default.component';
import {RoutingModule} from './routing/routing.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {CarouselModule} from 'ngx-owl-carousel-o';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DefaultComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule,
    RoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CarouselModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following options. I just added the 'navText' configuration to it. I'm using a font icon library called [Themify Icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/themify-icons) for the right and left arrow icons, you can also use Font Awesome if you want.

```
customOptions: OwlOptions = {
    loop: true,
    mouseDrag: true,
    touchDrag: true,
    pullDrag: true,
    dots: false,
    navText: [
      '<i class="ti-angle-left"></i>',
      '<i class="ti-angle-right"></i>',
    ],
    navSpeed: 600,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1
      },
      400: {
        items: 2
      },
      760: {
        items: 3
      },
      1000: {
        items: 4
      }
    },
    nav: true
  };
```

Comment: I replaced with your code, but arrows didn't appeared. Maybe there is option somehow to change styles of arrows from css file?

Comment: You would need to install Themify Icons npm package and also add its node modules path in the 'angular.json' file.

Comment: Do you mean "node_modules/themify_icons/themify_icons/_themify-icons.scss" file?

Comment: Yes, in the styles array.